# io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-studio, parcelfiledescriptor

I Was Trying to update API level 28 to 30. This is a photo editor project. the app is run successfully but when picking the photo for the crop from local storage the app not work and I saw this error. "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" when I am trying with old API like API 28 the app is working fine. I check the Logcat and not find any solution. also, I am trying to improve my manifest permission. but the manifest permission is ok. I think the problem is below java code or method.

[image]

Please anyone help me.

Logcat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:315)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:220)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1505)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1345)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1293)
        at com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapLoadTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadTask.java:101)
        at com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapLoadTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadTask.java:45)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Java:

```
 public class BitmapLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, BitmapLoadTask.BitmapWorkerResult> {

    private static final String TAG = "BitmapWorkerTask";

    private final Context mContext;
    private Uri mInputUri;
    private Uri mOutputUri;
    private final int mRequiredWidth;
    private final int mRequiredHeight;

    private final BitmapLoadCallback mBitmapLoadCallback;

    public static class BitmapWorkerResult {

        Bitmap mBitmapResult;
        ExifInfo mExifInfo;
        Exception mBitmapWorkerException;

        public BitmapWorkerResult(@NonNull Bitmap bitmapResult, @NonNull ExifInfo exifInfo) {
            mBitmapResult = bitmapResult;
            mExifInfo = exifInfo;
        }

        public BitmapWorkerResult(@NonNull Exception bitmapWorkerException) {
            mBitmapWorkerException = bitmapWorkerException;
        }

    }

    public BitmapLoadTask(@NonNull Context context,
                          @NonNull Uri inputUri, @Nullable Uri outputUri,
                          int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight,
                          BitmapLoadCallback loadCallback) {
        mContext = context;
        mInputUri = inputUri;
        mOutputUri = outputUri;
        mRequiredWidth = requiredWidth;
        mRequiredHeight = requiredHeight;
        mBitmapLoadCallback = loadCallback;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected BitmapWorkerResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (mInputUri == null) {
            return new BitmapWorkerResult(new NullPointerException("Input Uri cannot be null"));
        }

        try {
            processInputUri();
        } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
            return new BitmapWorkerResult(e);
        }

        final ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
        try {
            parcelFileDescriptor = mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mInputUri, "r");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return new BitmapWorkerResult(e);
        }

        final FileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
        if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
            fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        } else {
            return new BitmapWorkerResult(new NullPointerException("ParcelFileDescriptor was null for given Uri: [" + mInputUri + "]"));
        }

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);
        if (options.outWidth == -1 || options.outHeight == -1) {
            return new BitmapWorkerResult(new IllegalArgumentException("Bounds for bitmap could not be retrieved from the Uri: [" + mInputUri + "]"));
        }

        options.inSampleSize = BitmapLoadUtils.calculateInSampleSize(options, mRequiredWidth, mRequiredHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap = null;

        boolean decodeAttemptSuccess = false;
        while (!decodeAttemptSuccess) {
            try {
                decodeSampledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);
                decodeAttemptSuccess = true;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor: ", error);
                options.inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true
in your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeting Android Q, you should define `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest file for  backwards compatibility reasons.

```
<manifest..>
    ...
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```